# Windows Service LockScreen

Tags: c++, winapi, service, windows-services, group-policy

I have a Windows service look for trigger situations. If one is found, it will lock the screen/log out of the user that is currently active. This is not normally possible as services can not properly run functions that need an interactive environment.

To get around this, I made help programs and then called them using CreateProcessAsUser. This has worked well for me, and has had no issues up till this point.

Trying this on another computer, I ran into Group Policy issues. It all works until CreateProcessAsUser is called and it return an error. The error being “Execution is prohibited by group policy”. An admin can start .exe files, but a normal user cannot. Thus, it breaks when the normal user is the one to start the help programs as it does not have the right to do so.

Been talking to some friends, and most say it should be doable to just start it with session 0 rights and skip the issue altogether. But far as I can tell, this is not possible by design. As it could create Shatter attacks and other issues if a lower security user could with help of a service run process in higher security modes.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: FWIW, I think that a group policy preventing your service from doing this, is doing exactly what it's supposed to for the reasons that you quote.

Comment: Still, Wondering if there is some magic way to work around this, Or if it dead in the water entirly. I know little about GP and how one could make this work.

Comment: Wouldn't your service run with sufficient credentials itself? But I do have to wonder who mismanaged the Group Policies so badly that you cannot run an executable, but can install a new service (!)

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) instead of `CreateProcessAsUser`. CreateProcessWithLogonW requires no special privileges, but the specified user account must be allowed to log on interactively.

Comment: @Jeaninez - MSFT, Fairly sure it would not work. The problem is also that lock, logout etc demand an interactive session. Why I can not just do it from session 0. if I use LogonW I am sure it is not run under the current loged in users interactive session.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no winapi to realize what you want.